# Some nice OO library to handle directories in PHP

Tags: php, oop, filesystems

Is there any nice "common" OO library for handling files and directories, like recursive copy, delete, read and such? Native php functions sucks and their like OO approuch. Any tips on this would be helpfull I dont want re-invent the wheel.

Comment: duh... why bad question?

Comment: I may not agree with the downvote, but I also disagree with statement "native php functions suck".  Native php functions provide more than enough to handle any possible requirement with very little work.

Comment: Aye, you're probably being downvoted for the unnecessary jab at PHP functions. It's almost flamebait.

Comment: Tip of the day: Scan the manual again, sooo many functions, objects, iterators and don't skip the SPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of classes in [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php):

[`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)
[`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)
[`SPLFileObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)
[`SPLFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

...to name the ones you are most likely to find useful.

There are no native recursive copy, delete etc classes but it would be easy to roll you own based on these SPL classes.

Answer (score 1):

[Directory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directory.php) class is supposed to be the "nice" "OO" way of handling directories. I think it succeeds in being nice and OO. Anything other than  that is re-inventing the wheel ;).

Comment: Yeah but they dont copy nor delete the files.

Comment: Then, i guess, the answer is no, there is no native oo-way to do that. Check out SPL as DaveRandom suggests.